# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnind4jcpu in java.library.path

Tags: deeplearning4j, java.library.path

I started using the 1.0.0-beta2 version of deeplearning4j and I am getting the following error when attempting to start:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnind4jcpu in java.library.path

In looking around, I came across this issue: https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4j/issues/1687

where the solution seemed to be an incomplete set of packages. I have confirmed that I have nd4j-native-platform-1.0.0-beta2.jar, but this jar file contains no libraries as what seemed to be the problem in the issue mentioned above.

I have looked at the maven repository and things are strange there as well:

For https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.nd4j/nd4j-native-platform, the list of files under "View All" seems incomplete for the 1.0.0-beta2 version and the existing jar files under older versons also don't seem to contain any binaries so I am unsure as to where the binaries are supposed to be.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a specific OS you are trying? It should work out of the box if you just use platform. Platform includes numerous dependencies. I'm not  sure what "incomplete" might be, but if you browse the real maven central (not this website, please do not use it):
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/nd4j/nd4j-native/1.0.0-beta2/

You'll see jars for everything here. We have pretty good coverage publishing for every OS all the way to android and IOS.

Comment: This is just for WIndows. I have not had any luck finding the location of the library and have looked in a number of jar files. It also seems that for the issue mentioned, the answer was incorrect as the libraries were never in the nd4j-native-platform jar file.

Comment: The nd4j-native-platform library comes with everything, including windows. There is a maven classifier with windows right there if you look at my link.  You've got to be doing your build wrong. It's right here: https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/blob/master/nd4j/nd4j-backends/nd4j-backend-impls/nd4j-native-platform/pom.xml#L101 I code with dl4j on windows every day and do not have this issue. You do not need to do anything but add the declaration  to your pom.xml

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem was due to maven stupidity and a low disk condition. The jar referenced by the nd4j-native-platform jar could not be downloaded and maven was not complaining.

Comment: Ahh got it. Yes that can happen. Glad you got it fixed!